# How to use CvAvgSdv in openCV + VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I read from this thread - [Get most accurate image using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831074/get-most-accurate-image-using-opencv) - that I can use variance to measure which of the input images are the sharpest. I can't seem to find a tutorial for this. I am very new to openCV. Right now, my code scans images from a folder and stores them using vector

```
for (int ct = 0; ct < images.size() ; ct++) {
    //should i put the cvAvgSdv function here?
    waitKey(0);
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Update: I called this fxn:
    cvAvgSdv(images[ct],&scalar_mean,&std_dev); 
and it gave me an error:
    No suitable conversion function from cv::Mat to const cvArr * exists.

Can I use the fxn without converting the Mat to iplImage? If not, what's the easiest way to convert the Mat?

Comment: you could try cvAvgSdv(images[ct]->imageData,&scalar_mean,&std_dev);

Comment: you could try cvCreateImage, this will help you to convert mat to iplImage, sorry for last answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it is.
you should calc like this:

```
CvScalar mean, std_dev; 
cvAvgSdv(img,&mean,&std_dev,NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks! Should I put that in a loop? Do I get a float as a result?

Comment: yes, you put them in the loop to calc each image. The results is a CvScalar which is include 4 channals. You should compare each of them.

Comment: Thank you! I am updating the question as I have another problem. Will you please check it one last time? Thnx @slggamer